# org.hibernate.exception.DataException: Could not execute JDBC batch update

Tags: java, exception, jdbc, axis

```
AxisFault

 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException  
 faultSubcode:  
 faultString: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: Could not execute JDBC batch update  
 faultActor:  
 faultNode:  
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:XXX


org.hibernate.exception.DataException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:222)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:129)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:601)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1782)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2938)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:395)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
    at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
    at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnderstandChecker.java:62)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at stickler.webservice.v1.WebServicePortBindingStub.publish(WebServicePortBindingStub.java:548)
    at com.infopath.main.Main.moduleRequestOne(Main.java:41)
    at com.infopath.main.Main.main(Main.java:23)
```

Comment: We're going to need a few more details...

Comment: what's the code where this exception arise? what's the driver and the database you're using?

Comment: This can not be the full stack-trace (including causes), just add more details.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for pointing out that this is not the full stack-trace. I put in some more try-catch blocks and saw the total stack trace:
"Data truncation: Data too long for column 'data' at row 1
 at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:2018)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1449)
 at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
 at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
 ... 43 more"

Comment: possible duplicate of [org.hibernate.exception.DataException although is catched](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15983371/org-hibernate-exception-dataexception-although-is-catched)

Answer (score 1):

```
Data truncation: Data too long for column 'data'
```

This means that you're trying to store in the 'data' column a string that's longer that its maximum allowed size according to the database. You must increase this size. For instance if you're using JPA directly:

```
@Column(name = "data", length = 65536)
public string getData() {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception is due to failed batch update. It not only means that the data in the column is larger than the permissible size but also could mean the incompatible data. For ex. the data in Date column could be in a wrong format i.e. column expects 'yyyy-mm-dd' format where as the data is in 'dd-mm-yyyy'. There are many other situation where the incompatible data cause failure of update.

Answer (score -1):

Just use @Lob in POJO definition of column.