# org.hibernate.exception.DataException although is catched

Tags: java, hibernate, exception

I am working with Hibernate (hibernate3.jar) with and object "Cliente", like this:

```
public class Cliente {
    private nombre;
    ...
    //set and get
}
```

The "nombre" attribute is mapped as:

```
<property name="nombre" type="string">
    <column name="nombre" length="30" not-null="true" />
</property>
```

As you can see above, there is a character length limit squals to `30`. Here the things get complicated... I am trying to update the name with a long name in order to force an error:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

try{
    cliente.setNombre(textField.getText()); //here
    session.update(cliente);
    tx.commit();
    list.repaint();
} catch (org.hibernate.exception.DataException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data entered too long");
    session.getTransaction().rollback();
} finally {
    session.close();
}
```

When the name exceeds the limit allowed, this excepcion `org.hibernate.exception.DataException` is thrown (as debbuger details, it is at line `x.commit();`:

```
SEVERE: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'nombre' at row 1
Hibernate: update gimnasiobd.cliente set nombre=? where idCliente=?
abr 12, 2013 7:40:07 PM org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener performExecutions
SEVERE: Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.DataException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
```

What's the problem here? Well... although the excepcion is catched (the JOPtion is shown), the exception is shown in the console as if the catch does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Give the large length for column name nombre. For example

```
<column name="nombre" length="200" not-null="true" />
```

Or remove length attribute . It will take max value automatically defined for String as per your DB vendor

see below links

[Solution1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509769/how-to-increase-length-of-a-string-in-mysql-while-mapping-using-jpa)

also see below link

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281188/text-field-using-hibernate-annotation
```

Comment: Yes, but when attribute is removed, the exception persists. Supposing that I am using a column `nombre varchar(255)` in mysql db. If I set a name with a large size than this, the exception is thrown too.

Comment: Go to DB client and see what is the length of  column Nombre. It should be of length 255

Comment: Yes, it is set with 255. Let me try your link.

Answer (score 0):

Surround the `rollback()` with another try-catch to see if it's the cause of the exception

```
catch (org.hibernate.exception.DataException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data entered too long");
    try {
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
    } catch (HibernateException ex) {}
}
```

I wasn't able to determine from the documentation why a rollback would be throwing a DataException, but the javadoc states that the rollback can throw a HibernateException which is a superclass of DataException.

Comment: Noup, the exception is throw again, and again and again

Comment: That's bizarre.  Try surrounding the `session.close()` statement with a try-catch just for the helluvit, although I don't think that's throwing the exception - I just can't think of any other cause.

Comment: haha me too... surrounding the session.close() dit not make the trick